# bivariate polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, sp.spectral-theory, fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Hello,

Let $p(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^M\sum_{n=1}^N a_{m,n}x^{m-1}y^{n-1}$ be a bivariate polynomial where $\{a_{m,n}\}$ are complex.

If $(x_k, y_k), k=1,2,\cdots, MN-1$ are roots of $p(x,y)=0$ where $|x_k|=|y_k|=1$ for $k=1,2,\cdots,MN-1$.

How can I show that there exists another different solution, that is, $p(x_{MN}, y_{MN})=0$ where $|x_{MN}|=|y_{MN}|=1$ and $(x_{MN}, y_{MN}) \neq (x_{k}, y_{k})$, $k=1,2,\cdots,MN-1$?

Thanks a lot.

---

Substituting $x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} + i\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $y = \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2} + i\frac{2s}{1+s^2}$ into $p(x,y)$, we get $p(t,s)$. Then $p(x,y) = 0$ implies $p_r(t,s)\triangleq\Re(p(t,s))=0$ and $p_i(t,s)\triangleq\Im(p(t,s))=0$. Then, the problem becomes:

1)What is the number of common roots of $p_r(t,s)$ and $p_i(t,s)$.

2)If there are $MN-1$ common roots, will there be another common root?

Any comments?

---

Comment: Do you really mean for your indices to start at $1$? so all your polynomials are divisible by $xy$?

Comment: This has a certain homework flavor. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry, there is a constant in p(x,y).

Comment: This is NOT a homework.

I just tested the statement with numerical examples and would like to know if it is true theoretically.

Can anyone offer some hints?

Comment: Are there any properties of unimodular roots ($|z|=1$) of a bivariate polynomial equation? For example, the number of unimodular roots, the space containing the unimodular roots and the common unomodular roots of two bivariate polynomial equations? Thanks.

Comment: There is a rational parametrization of unimodular complex numbers $|x|=1 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} + i\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, with $t$ real, which is also allowed to take the value $\infty$. Similar for $|y|=1$. Plugging these parametrizations into your complex polynomial and looking at its real and imaginary parts, after clearing denominators, you'll find a system of two real polynomials in two real variables. Don't see any reason why this system would be any simpler than a 2-variable polynomial system. If any of its roots are complex, you've got a counter example.

Comment: Are you counting "distinct" roots, or you take multiplicities into account?